# Increment variable in BigQuery (in case when)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to increment a variable after some condition.

```
DECLARE cpt INT64;
SET cpt = 0;

WITH CPT As (
SELECT
  Date,
  A,
  B,
  C,
  D,
  E,
  F,
  G,

  CASE
    WHEN B > 1 THEN ---Vérification si le capteur est fiable
      CASE
        WHEN A>1 THEN ---Cas numéro 1
          CASE
            WHEN A < (B * (1 + 0.05)) AND A > (B * (1 - 0.05)) THEN (cpt+1)
          END
        WHEN C>1 THEN ---Cas numéro 2
          CASE
            WHEN E>1 THEN  ---Si la donnée est fiable
              CASE
                WHEN (C+E) < (B * (1 + 0.05)) AND (C+E) > (B * (1 - 0.05)) THEN (cpt + 1)
              END
            ELSE --- Si elle ne l'est pas
              CASE
                WHEN D >= 0 AND F>= 0 AND G>=0  THEN ---On vérifie que toutes ces données sont >= 0
                  CASE
                    WHEN (C+(D+F+G)) < (B * (1 + 0.05)) AND (C+(D+F+G)) > (B * (1 - 0.05)) THEN (cpt + 1)
                  END
                ELSE  ---Si elles ne le sont pas
                  CASE
                    WHEN (C+0) < (B * (1 + 0.05)) AND (C+0) > (B * (1 - 0.05)) THEN (cpt + 1)
                  END
              END
          END
        WHEN E>1 THEN  ---Cas numéro 3
          CASE
            WHEN D>=0 AND G >= 0 AND F>=0 THEN ---On vérifie que toutes ces données sont >= 0
              CASE
                WHEN (E + (G+D+F)) < (B * (1 + 0.05)) AND (E + (G+D+F)) > (B * (1 - 0.05)) THEN (cpt + 1)
              END
            ELSE
              CASE
                WHEN (E + 0) < (B * (1 + 0.05)) AND (E + 0) > (B * (1 - 0.05)) THEN (cpt + 1)
              END
          END
      END
  END AS Cpt_Vap_Stable,
 
FROM
  my_table
WHERE DATETIME_DIFF(CAST("2020-05-11 21:00:00" AS DATETIME),DATETIME(Date),HOUR)<=1 AND DATETIME_DIFF(CAST("2020-05-11 21:00:00" AS DATETIME),DATETIME(Date),SECOND) > 1
ORDER BY Date
)
```

This code doesn't work. I have so much other condition so it's just an example to show you my problem. Thank you.

EDIT :
[That's what's I've got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5gVL.png)
But I want the variable to increment.

So to explain a little bit I have a table with some column and I do some CASE WHEN and in the OUTPUT table I just want the TIMESTAMP and this famous counter.

That's what I want :

|2020-05-11 21:00:00 | 0
|2020-05-11 21:01:00 | 1 *Verified*
|2020-05-11 21:02:00 | 2 *Verified*
|2020-05-11 21:03:00 | 3 *Verified*
|2020-05-11 21:04:00 | 3 *Not Verified*
|2020-05-11 21:05:00 | 3 *Not Verified*
|2020-05-11 21:04:00 | 4 *Verified*

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results so it is clear what you want to do.

Comment: I've just edit my post but I don't kow how to do a table on stackoverflow, so I took a screen of what I had

Comment: . . Explain the logic you want to implement with *text* tables -- before and after -- in the question.

Comment: [Why should you provide a Minimal Reproducible Example even for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the SUM function depending on a condition. For examle, let's say we have a table with the ID column and there are three different IDs (1,2,3), therefore I could do the following:

```
 SELECT sum(case when ID = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as new_column FROM 
 `<table>`
```

This way we will have the variable new_column as the number of 1s in the ID column.

You can also order by some column, for example:

```
SELECT sum(case when ID = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over(order by 
datecolumn) as new_column FROM `<table>`
```

Nested conditions using a public BigQuery dataset:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE
        WHEN venueSurface = "grass" THEN 
         CASE
            WHEN venueCapacity = 50398 THEN
               CASE 
                  WHEN venueState = "CO" THEN 1
                  ELSE 0 
               END
            WHEN venueCapacity= 31042 THEN 2 ELSE 0 
         END
      END
)
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.baseball.games_wide`
```

Comment: The problem is that's don't work for me because I have a lot of case when imbricate and on BigQuery it tells me that "Syntax error: Unexpected keyword SELECT at [19:11]"

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem since you can nest as many conditions as you want, for example:
      SELECT sum(case when ID = 1 then 1 when ID = 2 then 2 else 0 end) FROM `table`

Comment: I just update the schema of my code look what I mean

Comment: The Syntax error means that you have something badly formatted in your query, so check if all your conditions are well closed and well nested, I have made an example with a public BigQuery dataset and I got no issues, I have updated my answer with the example. I suggest you try to do that in short pieces of code and thus increase the query.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want `row_number()`:

```
select t.*, row_number() over (order by date)
from t;
```

You haven't explained in the question what the real logic is that you want to implement, but `row_number()` seems like the solution.

Comment: Thank you but I want to my variable to increase each time that the conditions is verified, and when it's not i don't it to change just still the same.